# Electrolysis of molten CaOH and CaCl

Tags: electrolysis

So recently I have been trying to get elemental Calcium but I only found a cheap solution in electrolysis of molten $\ce{CaCl2}$ (thats because calcium chloride is very cheap) and I am not sure If it would work Can you give me advise? I also wonder If it would work on $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$?

Would the reaction be like

$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 -> Ca + 2 OH}$$

and

$$\ce{CaCl2 -> Ca + Cl2}$$

or something else ( I am 13 so I dont know much about chemistry )

Comment: It's much more efficient to buy calcium than to obtain it yourself by electrolysis...

Answer (score 1):

You'll get nowhere with calcium hydroxide. Try to melt it, and it gives off water, becoming calcium oxide. Try to melt *that*, and you'll melt your container first. And your electrodes.

Electrolysis of calcium chloride works commercially, but it's very difficult in a home lab. I've seen discussions from people who have tried, but I don't think any of them were successful.

**Please don't try to do this** if you don't have much experience with chemistry. Start with something like copper-plating; copper sulfate is easy to get, and you can do it with an aqueous solution at room temperature. Working with molten salts and alkali/alkaline-earth metals is a *really* bad idea if you're just starting to learn.